# having dependency issues while installing a package in Debian GNU/Linux 6.0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dependencies, packages, debian

I am trying to install one package but it depends on some other packages. While installing it aborts and tells me the following:

```
Depends: python (>= 2.6.6-7~) but 2.6.6-3+squeeze7 is to be installed
Depends: python-sqlalchemy (>= 0.7~) but 0.6.3-3+squeeze1 is to be installed
```

I don't know how to solve this dependancy problems. I looked at google and installed

```
python-all-dev
```

from: http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/python-all-dev

But it didn't solve the problem. Can anyone shed some more light on this issue. Thanks

Comment: Please post the full messages you received so we can see what happened. Thanks

Comment: actually the package i want to install does not support debian squeeze, so i need to upgrade it to wheezy. i am doing it now

Comment: You could have just used [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) and installed all the needed dependencies. Upgrading your whole system for one program seems to be overkill to me

Comment: actually it's a vm and i will run only this program. so it's worth